# Finder not showing Windows server networks

Tags: macos, finder, windows, file-sharing

We have a network with 40 machines and all of our machines are showing in Finder except for our Windows Server 2011 which is not showing under network computers in Finder.

I can connect using Go -> Connection to server -> smb://ipaddress but I'm wondering if there is a way to get it to also show as a machine in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added each Mac to the Windows workgroup?

1. System Preferences > Network
2. Select the relevant network interface from the sidebar (Ethernet, Wifi etc)
3. Click 'Advanced'
4. Click 'WINS'
5. Enter the name of the Windows workgroup in 'Workgroup:'
6. Click the `+` button and enter the IP address of your Windows server in place of `0.0.0.0`
7. Click 'OK' and 'Apply'